# Check if child of array is object or array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a class which allows to retrieve an array according to the syntax "key.key2.key3".

For now, no problem. Problems occur when one of the keys is an object.
Because I have to check that the key is an array or an object

My script bug when I try to determine if type of key[key2] == array or if type of key->key2 == object. One of the two conditions may be false. (If script tests that key[key2] == array, and that key2 is an object, for example).

Is there a way to verify that key2 is an array or an object without doing key[key2] or key->key2 ?

Thanks.

Comment: share your code

Comment: [`is_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) [`is_object()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php)

Comment: I have already used is_array() and is_object() but not as in the example of trincot. The example of trincot works, I did not use these two functions in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform the test on the parent, *before* accessing the key.

Here is an example:

```
function findValue($a, $s) {
    $keys = explode(".", $s);
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if (is_object($a)) {
            $a = $a->$key;
        } else if (is_array($a)) {
            $a = $a[$key];
        } else { // unexpected
            return null;
        }
    }
    return $a;
}

// Sample data: mix of object and array:
$arr = [
    "key1" => (object) [
        "key2" => [
            "key3" => 42
        ]
    ]
];

echo findValue($arr, "key1.key2.key3"); // 42
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `is_array()`?

Docs [here](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-array.php)